# How to resize image on orientation change..?

Tags: android, xml

I have an image(320x210), I call the image from drawable folder in xml file...in portrait mode its working fine, but while I change the device to LANDSCAPE the image is not fitting prorerly..?? How to resolve that issue..??
Here is my xml code i tried

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"(here i tried with "fitXY" also)
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/srkpic"/>
```

And also i tried with this method
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH)
{
}
but this method is available only if we extends with "View" which is not meet my requirement. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the code below on change of your orientation, where imgHeaderFooter is your bitmap

```
 imgHeaderFooter.setDensity(1/2);

        int width = imgHeaderFooter.getWidth();
        int height = imgHeaderFooter.getHeight();

        int screenWidth = UseMe.getDispWidth()/2;

        float scaleWidth = ((float) screenWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) height) / height;      

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth,scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgHeaderFooter,0,0,width,height,matrix,true);
        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

        imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY); 
        imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);
```

Comment: what is that...UseMe     int screenWidth = UseMe.getDispWidth()/2;

Comment: UseMe.getDispWidth()/2 is actually the screen width of android device divided by 2, nothing but WindowManager w = getWindowManager(); 
  Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
  int width = d.getWidth()/2; 
  int height = d.getHeight()/2;

Comment: Hi, arun i tried as you told but its not working, still i am getting the same problem. Image is not reSize....I written that code onConfigurationChanged(configuration confi) method.

Answer (score 2):

Provide an alternate resource sized for landscape under `res/drawable-land` for srkpic.

Comment: ya..that i tried and its working..but app is restarting..that i dont want. Any other way other then that..???

Comment: You need to check android:configChange attribute of the activity.